# preventDefault() doesn't work and the page get reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have this link inside one of the 2 tabs in my page but whenever I click on `a.editReview` the page get reloaded and `e.preventDefault()` seems not working. I know the problem is somewhere else but I can't really see it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Activate our reviews */
    $().reviews('.starReviews');

    $('.tabs a').on("click", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.panel').hide();
        $('.tabs a.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active').blur();
        var panel = $this.attr('href');
        $(panel).fadeIn(250);

        return false;
    });//end click

    $('.tabs li:first a').click();

    $("a.editReview").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var reviewId = $(this).data('review-id');
        alert(reviewId);        
    }); //edit review click function

});//document ready function
```

```
<div class="eventFeedbackBottomContainer">
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#panel1" tabindex="1">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel2" tabindex="2">Hotels</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="rightFeedbackBottomContainer">
        <a href="/addReview/<?php echo escape($eventReview->getData()->race_id);?>/" id="" class="Smallbut">Add Review</a>
    </div>

    <div id="panel1" class="panel">
        <div class="feedbacksContainer">
            <div class="show-reviews"></div><!-- a.editReview is inside each review loaded from a javascript file in this div-->
        </div>                                
    </div>

    <div id="panel2" class="panel"/>
</div>
```

***UPDATE***

As suggested by dfsq I started reading about delegation and this is a good start for whoever is struggling to understand it, like myself!
[Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: What's this supposed to do -> `$().reviews('.starReviews');`

Comment: sorry I didn't post it because everything else worked until I wanted to add this link. It basically load all the reviews from my database inside `<div class="show-reviews">`. Each review has a link to edit (which doesn't work) `<a class="editReview" data-review-id= "'.$fReviews['reviewID'].'" href="">Edit</a>';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the situation when you need to deletage event to a parent container:

```
$(".eventFeedbackBottomContainer").on("click", "a.editReview", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var reviewId = $(this).data('review-id');
      alert(reviewId);        
});
```

This is the case because links are loaded dynamically after DOMContentLoaded event, you don't have `.editReview` links available on page load so you can't bind event to them. But you can bind click event listener to a parent container for example `.eventFeedbackBottomContainer` and listen all click events bubbling from all child elements up the DOM tree. This way even if you inject relevant links later, your event listener will be able to detect clicks on them.

Comment: thanks! This is when I realise that I need to read a bit more about delegation. I have always struggled. It worked like a charm. You have just been too quick to reply though. I have to wait 3 more minutes to accept your answer! Cheers +1

Comment: Yes, delegation is pretty cool thing. It's also much more efficient because you bind only one event listener handling all elements instead of binding separate for each one.

Comment: sorry, just one more question. now `var reviewId = $(this).data('review-id');` gives me an undefined value probably because of the delegation. how can I get the data-review-id of each review?

Comment: Actually even though there is delegation `this` points to current a `a.editReview` anyway. Look: http://jsfiddle.net/PwQLf/. Make sure HTML is correct and you have `data-review-id` on your links.

Comment: fixed it. the problem was that `<a class="editReview" data-review-id= "'.$fReviews['reviewID'].'" href="">Edit</a>` was inside `<div class="current-review"></div>`. Everything worked as soon as I moved it outside.

Answer (score -2):

Try Like this, It will work:

```
$("a.editReview").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var reviewId = $(this).data('review-id');
  alert(reviewId);        
});
```